# How Can i Rename All Files in a Directory using For Loop?

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my snippet:

```
#!/bin/sh

for fname in *
do
      if [! -d "$fname"]
      then
          WHAT CAN I DO
      fi
done
```

All new named files has to have this format O.fname - as you see preceeded by O.
Can you please help? I know i have to use mv somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files are renamed using mv, so just do

```
mv "$fname" "O.$fname"
```

in the loop.

Comment: can u not just use rename instead of mv ?

Comment: @thegeek: You can use rename if a) you know it is installed and b) you know which one is installed. There's one tool named rename which accepts a perl regex and a list of file and another which accepts two strings and a list of files. Neither of them is installed on all systems.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the mv inside the loop. Also, in the if statement, there is a space between the `[` and the `!`

```
for fname in *
do
    if [ ! -d "$fname" ]
    then
        mv "$fname" "O.$fname"
    fi
done
```

Comment: sepp2k's answer is better: `mv "$fname" "O.$fname"` protects against spaces in file names.